# How to use const in the declaration of a function

Tags: c++, opencv, reference, constants

In opencv, I happened to modify a variable which was passed to my function as constant:

```
void someFunction(const cv::Mat matrix)
{
  double value = 5.0;
  matrix /= value;
}
```

Not only it compiles, but also the matrix remains modified after the call to `someFunction(matrix)`, even though I haven't passed `matrix` as a reference. My explanation for this code to compile is that I am not actually changing any member of `matrix` in `someFunction`, but the contents of the address pointed by the pointer `data`of `matrix`, but I am not really sure.
As I was a bit puzzled I tried to reproduce this situation in a little program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo;
{ 
 private:
  int* ptr;

public:
  Foo()
  {
    ptr = new int[1];
    ptr[0] = 1;
  }

  const Foo& operator += ( const Foo& obj) const
  {
    this->ptr[0] += obj.ptr[0];
    return *this;
  }

};

void changeConst(const Foo var)
{
  Foo foo;
  var += foo;
}

int main() 
{
  Foo obj;
  changeConst(obj);
  return 0;
}
```

It turns out that this program compiles and effectively changes `ptr[0]`of `obj`. I found out that if  I declare the operator `+=` this way:

```
Foo& operator += ( const Foo& obj)
```

It does not compile. Why is this? This discovery produced many questions in me. Is there a way to prevent the change of the contents of a pointer in a function? what is the meaning of a function returning a constant reference (`const Foo&`)? What should be intended when declaring a function `const`? In short, how should I use `const` in the declaration of a function?

Comment: I'm not sure how `matrix \= value;` compiles.

Comment: @chris The semantics of `cv::Mat` are peculiar to say the least.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Perhaps `/=` would work, but not `\=` AFAIK.

Comment: @chris Yes, not even `cv::Mat` should make sense out of `\=`.

Comment: @Manu: What?  By value const is quite useful for preventing accidental modification (assuming the object is implemented sanely, not like the example here), selecting a preference for const versions of member functions, and in general creates optimization opportunities.

Comment: @chris and @juanchopanza: oops, I made a very silly mistake. Of course, I meant `/=`. Edited
@Ben Voigt: Could you provide an example where your statement is proved? As far as I know I implemented sanely my matrix in my original code, and I got the results shown in the question

Comment: @BenVoigt's point is that you shouldn't be able to modify `matrix`, therefore `cv::Mat` is not sanely implemented. I have to agree with that.

Comment: @juanchopanza ahh I see, I misunderstood him. Right, maybe a bug should be arisen to the OpenCV guys..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the `const` from the signature results in a compilation error because you cannot call a non-const member function from a `const` instance.

The reason the `const` version compiles and seems to do something counter-intuitive is that you are modifying an object pointed to by the `Mat` (assuming you meant `/=`) or `Foo` object, but you are not modifying the data member itself, namely the pointer.

Whether it makes sense to design types which exhibit this behaviour is another matter. Personally, I would say that allowing modification of a  `const cv::Mat` via `operator /=` violates the [*principle of least astonishment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). `cv::Mat` seems to implement reference semantics (it is essentially a header and a pointer to a data block) but it could have implemented as to provide reasonable `const` correctness. It would not pass any code review I was involved in.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, `cv::Mat` is metadata about a matrix, with the actual data shared and reference-counted, like `std::shared_ptr`

So `const cv::Mat` is like `const std::shared_ptr<double>` -- you can't bind it to a new location, but you can modify the data pointed to.

You're looking for something equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<const double>`, and after reading [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) it doesn't look like any such thing exists.  Even stranger, it's possible to turn a "read-only" `InputArray` parameter into a `Mat` smart pointer.  So either there's a secret way of creating `Mat` smart pointers that prohibit modifications, or else `InputArray` isn't so read-only at all.

As juanchopanza said, this should have failed a design review.  Providing a smart pointer class with shared ownership of the data is all fine and good, but:

- If you have shared semantics, the class name should reflect that.  No one would be confused if `MPtr` worked like `std::shared_ptr`.
- The confusion between read-only and writable runs much deeper, as evidenced by the conversion from `InputArray` to `Mat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Foo& operator += ( const Foo& obj) const
{
    this->ptr[0] += obj.ptr[0];
    return *this;
}
```

You can tell, this operator:

1) returns const reference to Foo;

2) accepts const reference to Foo;

3) doesn't change any member in the class it is declared.

This is legit, because here you change the object, ptr points to, but not the ptr itself (it still points to the same location). And the value passed to the changeConst function can be accepted by the += operator. These function don't change anything in the Foo class, since it only has a pointer. However, data that pointer points to IS changed.

I recommend you watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7arYbAhu0aw) video if you struggling understanding how does const work.

Comment: Except if your object is a representation of a pointer to a foo, it should be named accordingly.  Copying an object named `Foo` should not result in only one representation of foogacity.